# Eclipse indent html content between <li>/li> tags

Tags: html, eclipse, formatting, ide

Anyone knows how do i configure eclipse for indent html code from this:

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item">Download (Atualizado em: <b>04/08/2021</b>)
  </li>
</ul>
```

to this:

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item">
    Download (Atualizado em: <b>04/08/2021</b>)
  </li>
</ul>
```

or maybe:

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item">Download (Atualizado em: <b>04/08/2021</b>)</li>
</ul>
```

I'm using eclipse's default WTP HTML editor (1.1.501.v202101180039) (I made sure this is the default editor that opens the file). Also, all other editors (Default text and Jboss Tools Editor, for example) indent the code in the same way.

Here's the configuration window for the html editor (HTML files -> Editor)

[image: Here is the Editor configuration window]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which Eclipse version do you have and which editor (there are more than one) do you use to edit HTML files?

Comment: Hi, it is the 2021-06 release (4.20.0). I'm using the default html editor

Comment: Which one is the default editor depends on which IDE package you have (and maybe also on how you have configured it and which additional plugins you have installed).  Please improve your question instead of adding comments.